# why is a remote link breaking out of iframe?

Tags: iframe

I have a remote link that is breaking out of an iframe in mobile only. Works fine on desktop. When I refresh the browser in mobile with desktop view it works fine, go figure. Is there a way to fix this so will load correctly? url - https://www.thegolfcourselocator.com

Answer (score 0):

you should provide the iframe with the css value:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

also make sure you have set the proper width settings.